# useful libraries for asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to hear about usefull free libraries for asp.net mvc 3
I heard about 2 good libraries

1. Fluent validation
2. MvcContrib

Does someone know more of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

checkout nuget for all these packages:
   http://nuget.org/List/Packages/EFCodeFirst.SqlServerCompact

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/T4Scaffolding

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/MvcScaffolding

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Newtonsoft.Json

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Lucene

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/YUICompressor.NET

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/WebActivator

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/51Degrees.mobi

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Facebook.Helper

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Twitter.Helper

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/MvcSiteMapProvider

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/microsoft-web-helpers

http://nuget.org/List/Search?packageType=Packages&searchCategory=All+Categories&searchTerm=Facebook&sortOrder=package-download-count&pageSize=10

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/MvcMailer

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/PagedList

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/PagedList.Mvc

hope it helps.brgds

Comment: thanks for the list. It will take me time to check them all out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

- [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) - [To work with Asp.Net MVC](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx)
- [ASP.NET MVC Project Awesome (ajax toolkit for asp.net mvc)](http://awesome.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

- [jQuery ASP.Net MVC Controls](http://mvcjquerycontrols.codeplex.com/)
- [MVC Controls Toolkit](http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/)
- [Fluent Filters](http://fluentfilters.codeplex.com/)
- [Sharp Architecture](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/sharp-architecture/wiki)